# Testing Ember Simple Auth in Ember App Kit with sinon

Tags: javascript, authentication, ember.js, sinon, ember-app-kit

I would like to mock server login responses when testing Ember Simple Auth in my Ember App Kit application. However, with the following code I get an opaque error 'Unexpected end of input' when the click action is called on the visit function :

```
var App;

module('Acceptances - SignIn', {
  setup: function(){
    App = startApp();
    this.xhr                = sinon.useFakeXMLHttpRequest();
    this.server             = sinon.fakeServer.create();
    this.server.autoRespond = true;
    sinon.spy(Ember.$, 'ajax');


    this.server.respondWith('POST', '/oauth/token', [
      200,
      { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      '{"access_token":"secret token 2!","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":7200}'
    ]);

  },
  teardown: function() {
    Ember.run(App, 'destroy');
  }
});

test('authentication works correctly', function() {   
  visit('/login').fillIn('#identification', "foo@bar.com").fillIn('#password', "password").click('button[type="submit"]').then(function() {
    ok(!exists('a:contains(Login)'), 'Login button is not displayed when authenticated');
  });
});
```

The #identification and #password input fields exists, and the submit button exists on the field that contains them.

I am including sinon and qunit in my headers. Am I calling sinon the wrong way or making some other mistake?

**Edit: Resolution:** By also including sinon-qunit the problem disappeared. It seems like you can not use sinon with Ember App Kit qunit tests without including sinon-qunit.

**Edit 2:** I open sourced an example with tests that mocks login responses with sinon here: https://github.com/digitalplaywright/eak-simple-auth

Comment: Can you close this question then or somehow mark this is solved?

Comment: I'd love to see the details of your solution. I'm attempting to get this to work, but currently if I mock logging in a user more than once within a acceptance test, I end up in an infinite loop of the tests running.

Comment: Sure, I open sourced a project using testing with sinon here: https://github.com/digitalplaywright/eak-simple-auth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I open sourced an example with tests that mocks login responses with sinon here at https://github.com/digitalplaywright/eak-simple-auth

The example is made using Ember App Kit, Ember Simple Auth, and Ember.

This is how I use mock login responses in the:

```
var App;

module('Acceptances - SignIn', {
  setup: function(){
    App = startApp();
    this.xhr                = sinon.useFakeXMLHttpRequest();
    this.server             = sinon.fakeServer.create();
    this.server.autoRespond = true;
    sinon.spy(Ember.$, 'ajax');


    this.server.respondWith('POST', '/oauth/token', [
      200,
      { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      '{"access_token":"secret token 2!","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":7200}'
    ]);

  },
  teardown: function() {
    Ember.run(App, 'destroy');
  }
});

test('authentication works correctly', function() {
  visit('/').then(function() {
    ok(exists('a:contains(Login)'), 'Login button is displayed when not authenticated');
    ok(!exists('a:contains(Logout)'), 'Logout button is not displayed when not authenticated');
  });

  visit('/login').fillIn('#identification', "foo@bar.com").fillIn('#password', "password").click('button[type="submit"]').then(function() {
    ok(!exists('a:contains(Login)'), 'Login button is not displayed when authenticated');
    ok(exists('a:contains(Logout)'), 'Logout button is displayed when authenticated');
  });
});
```