# Testing ember-simple-auth within Ember App Kit

Tags: authentication, ember.js, ember-app-kit, ember-qunit, ember-simple-auth

I'm attempting to perform integration/acceptance tests for my Ember app. I'm specifically testing user authentication (e.g. – submitting the login form) and protected pages/states that require authenticated users.

*General notes about my app:*

- Using [Ember App Kit](http://iamstef.net/ember-app-kit/)
- Using [ember-simple-auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth) for authentication
- I have [api-stubs](http://iamstef.net/ember-app-kit/guides/mock-and-proxy-requests.html) for my ember-simple-auth forms to hit using the Devise authorizer. These work fine when running the app in-browser.

*I have three problems:*

### 1. Devise Authenticator & Ephemeral Storage

From the ember-simple-auth API, it refers to using Ephemeral storage for tests. I have done so, [much like this](https://github.com/digitalplaywright/eak-simple-auth/blob/master/app/initializers/auth.js#L16-L18). However, it seems that the sessions is still getting stored in local storage. If I do not perform `localStorage.clear()` in each test setup/teardown tests fail because I remain logged in when each test runs after the first.

Am I able to prevent storing the session in local storage between each test when I'm using the Devise authenticator for my app?

### 2. Multiple Acceptance Tests

If I attempt to [log in a user](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/issues/132#issuecomment-39869865) in more than 1 `test()`, my tests spin off into an infinite loop. The first test will pass, but when the second test submits the login form the entire test suite stops and reboots.

**Integration Test #1**

```
App = null

module('Acceptance - Page #1',
  setup: ->
    App = startApp()

  teardown: ->
    Ember.run(App, 'destroy')
)

test('page #1 behind authentication', ->
  expect(1)

  visit('/page-1')
  fillIn('input#identification', 'foo@bar.com')
  fillIn('input#password', 'password')
  click('button[type="submit"]')
  andThen(->
    equal(true, true) # This test works fine
  )
)
```

**Integration Test #2**

```
App = null

module('Acceptance - Page #2',
  setup: ->
    App = startApp()

  teardown: ->
    Ember.run(App, 'destroy')
)

test('page #2 behind authentication', ->
  expect(1)

  visit('/page-2')
  fillIn('input#identification', 'foo@bar.com')
  fillIn('input#password', 'password')
  click('button[type="submit"]')
  andThen(->
    equal(true, true) # Never runs, tests start over, infinite loop begins
  )
)
```

### 3. EAK api-stubs & Testem

[EAK's api-stubs](http://iamstef.net/ember-app-kit/guides/mock-and-proxy-requests.html) do not seem to be available for Testem, so the "log in" process in these acceptance test when run via the command line/Testem fail.

I attempted [setting up sinon.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996749/testing-ember-simple-auth-in-ember-app-kit-with-sinon), but above mentioned issues have prevented me from deciding if it's actually working correctly or not. What is the best way to successfully stub logging in a user with ember-simple-auth? Is it possible to use EAK's api-stubs for Testem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @marcoow and a few other SO questions and GitHub issues I've been able to resolve all my problems:

#### 1. Devise Authenticator & Ephemeral Storage

I was using an outdated API option in my code. Updating to use the newer API's `storeFactory` option resolved my session `localStorage` issue.

```
#  app/initializers/simple-auth.coffee
if Ember.testing == true
  options = Ember.merge({ storeFactory: 'session-store:ephemeral' }, options)
```

#### 2. Multiple Acceptance Tests

This turned out to be related to another library I was loading called [fastclick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick). After updating my index file to only load this library in non-test environments, my form submission/infinite loop problems went away.

```
// app/index.html
<!-- @if tests=false -->
  <script src="/vendor/emberjs-touch/lib/ember-fastclick.js"></script>
<!-- @endif -->
```

#### 3. EAK api-stubs & Testem

I found other people facing [similar issues to me on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23080436/api-stubs-failing-when-running-tests-with-testem-in-ember-app-kit/23132532). Their questions were eventually responded to/resolved which helped me resolve me own issues. In the [comments of this GH issue](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit/issues/601#issuecomment-40706851), there is a link to a work-around to this issue. [Example here](https://github.com/tomclose/minimal_eak_test_stub_problem/commit/6fac4afdad4b552463e486dc1e9468937b2ab6dc).

Answer (score 2):

The example for setting the ephemeral store you're referencing above is outdated (if you're using that it basically has no effect and would default to the localStorage store) - for the new API see the API docs here: http://ember-simple-auth.simplabs.com/ember-simple-auth-api-docs.html#Ember-SimpleAuth-setup.

Maybe fixing that also fixes your 2nd problem (maybe the login form isn't actually displayed in the 2nd test as the user is still logged in anyway as you're using the localStorage store?).

Comment: Thank you. Using the updated API `storeFactory` option fixed #1. It has not fixed #2, however. The form is definitely displayed. The infinite loop begins immediately after the form is submitted. Any guidance? What portion of the ember-simple-auth library might I start stepping through?

Comment: I've been able to discover that the "infinite loop" is tied to the fact that the login form is *actually* submitting (as if no JS prevention) and refreshing the page on the 2nd login test. I have no idea why. For further debugging, I changed the `authenticate` action to fire on button click rather than form submit, but now the tests flip-flip passing on each run. I still don't know why.

Comment: Welp, after 3 days of dealing with this, I've finally found the problem. The library [fastclick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) was the culprit. I haven't looked into the details as of why, but removing fastclick from the page when testing resolves issue #2. Thank you for your help. In retrospect, I should've posted three separate questions so I could select your response as the answer to #1.